# url changed after last form submission how to go back on next selection?

Tags: javascript, forms

I've got a taxonomy filter select form on /books/ of my site. When a user selects a filter they'll be at:

```
/books/?genre=novel
```

When the list is paginated and they go to page 2 the parameter will carry over and they'll be at: `books/page/2/?genre=novel` Which works fine.

But if now they pick a different option from the form and the new genre doesn't have 2 pages **they will get a 404 page**. Because `/books/page/2/?genre=thriller` doesn't exist, but `/books/?genre=novel` does.

How can i stop this from happening?

Answer (score 1):

Just remove the paging in the genre change handler.
When the user changes the genre remove paging.

Comment: Indeed! That's what I need but how can I do it? I guess it would go in the javascript submit function?

Comment: Depends on how you handle genre change. Post the code and I will be able to help you better.

Answer (score 0):

Set action to the html form:

```
<form action="/books/" <!--other parameters-->">
```

Solution found on [this question](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/16516/pagination-how-to-remove-page-x-after-a-post-action-on-a-form-returning-to).